# Why is setTimeout executing immediately?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I have a simple JavaScript `setTimeout` function, but it is refusing to work

```
setTimeout(timeup(tc,chosen),10000)
```

... and this is the function:

```
timeup = function (clt,clo)
{   
    alert("time up")
}
```

... and the time up alert shows up immediately instead of after 10 seconds can someone tell me why this is happening please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because you're actually calling the `timeup(tc,chosen)` function inside the setTimeout function.

try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  timeup(tc,chosen);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: either that or you pass params as specified in [docs] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Parameters). So  your code should look like `setTimeout(timeup, 10000, tc, chosen)`

Answer (score 5):

In your example you call function and its result is passed to the `setTimeout` function.

Valid way to use function stored in variable here is to do:

```
setTimeout(timeup, 10000);
```

But it disallows passing parameters. To pass parameters, you can try with:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  timeup(tc,chosen);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: to ellaborate setTimeout expects a function that is "timeup". in your code you are calling it and what it returns (nothing) will be run as a function by setTimeout. if you want to pass arguments to a function in response to an event or setTimeout then you need to declare an extra function that does just that. as in this answer

Answer (score 4):

The point is you are calling the function previous to the timeout, when you add (tc, chosen) this fire the time up function.

Remove the `()`

> setTimeout(timeup,10000)

This will fire you function after 10000ms

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() {timeup(tc,chosen)},10000);
```

This puts your code in context of the timer, as opposed to inline execution, which you are now seeing.